# There is a Delay when refreshing / reload two divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I use codeigniter php frame work for my project I am able to refreah / reload my selected divs

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#button-refresh').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var refresh = function () {
        $("#newtotalinbox").load(window.location.href + " #newtotalinbox");
        $('#menu_unread').load(window.location.href + " #menu_unread");
    }

    setInterval(refresh, 60  * 1000);
    refresh();
});
</script>
```

**How ever there seems to be a few seconds delay between the two.
It does not change at the same time.**

> Question how to make sure the refresh / reload of both divs done at the same time?

Here is my dashboard view

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active">My Dashboard</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" id="button-refresh"><i class="fa fa-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary o-hidden h-100" id="inbox-dashbord">
                    <div class="card-body" id="total_inbox">
                        <div class="card-body-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-comments"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mr-5" id="newtotalinbox"><?php echo $total_inbox;?> New Messages</div>
                    </div>
                    <a class="card-footer text-white clearfix small z-1" href="<?php echo base_url('mail/inbox');?>">
                    <span class="float-left">View Inbox</span>
                    <span class="float-right">
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my Menu view

```
<!-- Navigation-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav" id="exampleAccordion">

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('dashboard');?>">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span class="nav-link-text">Dashboard</span>
            </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link btn btn-danger text-white" id="compose-button">
                <span class="nav-link-text">Compose</span>
            </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('mail/inbox');?>">Inbox <span id="menu_unread" class="text-white"><?php echo $menu_unread;?></span></a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('mail/sent');?>">
            <span class="nav-link-text">Sent</span>
            </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('mail/drafts');?>">Drafts</a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('mail/spam');?>">Spam
            </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('mail/trash');?>">Trash
            </a>
            </li>

            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link nav-link-collapse collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExamplePages" data-parent="#exampleAccordion">Events
                </a>
                <ul class="sidenav-second-level collapse" id="collapseExamplePages">
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('event/create');?>">Create Event</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('event/all');?>">View All Events</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php echo base_url('logout');?>">
                <i class="fa fa-fw fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

[image]

Comment: It's expected for different requests to take different times. You would need to set some sort of flag that would check that both ajax requests have successfully completed and only then refresh the content.

Comment: the problem with that, @i-- is that `$.load` does it's thing in it's own time, being asynchronous, you can't control it once you've executed it

Comment: yeah, good point @JaromandaX, he/she would need to tweak the code abit and use `$.ajax` or whatever other similar jQuery method is available. I wasn't really answering the questions, just giving some ideas.

Comment: the request would be for the same url twice ... so, yeah, best to use $.get/$.ajax, then do the data extraction "by hand" so to speak

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks for pointing that out will try it with ajax

Comment: @JaromandaX thanks ajax much better